# ip_cidr_range From tf.vars "is not a valid IP CIDR range: invalid CIDR address"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I've created a Terraform module for deploying VPCs in Google Cloud, part of which is:

```
  resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges" {
  name          = var.vpc_subnet_name
  ip_cidr_range = var.ip_cidr_range 
  region        = var.vpc_region
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.id
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = var.services_secondary_range_name
    ip_cidr_range = var.services_secondary_cidr_range
  }
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = var.pods_secondary_range_name
    ip_cidr_range = var.pods_secondary_cidr_range
  }
```

The *main.tf* file that *tf plan* accesses is updated by a Python script to provide unique CIDR ranges to ensure our deployed networks don't overlap. This sets the following:

```
ip_cidr_range = "10.51.0.0/20"
pods_secondary_cidr_range = "10.52.0.0/20"
services_secondary_cidr_range = "10.53.0.0/20"
```

However, *tf plan* complains:

*"ip_cidr_range" is not a valid IP CIDR range: invalid CIDR address:

*with module.ic-vpc.google_compute_subnetwork.network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges,

on .terraform/modules/ic-vpc/main.tf line 11, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges":
11:   ip_cidr_range = var.ip_cidr_range*

*"secondary_ip_range.0.ip_cidr_range" is not a valid IP CIDR range: invalid CIDR address:*

*with module.ic-vpc.google_compute_subnetwork.network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges,
on .terraform/modules/ic-vpc/main.tf line 16, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges":
16:     ip_cidr_range = var.services_secondary_cidr_range*

*"secondary_ip_range.1.ip_cidr_range" is not a valid IP CIDR range: invalid CIDR address:*

*with module.ic-vpc.google_compute_subnetwork.network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges,
on .terraform/modules/ic-vpc/main.tf line 20, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges":
20:     ip_cidr_range = var.pods_secondary_cidr_range*

The addresses look fine to me, unless I'm missing something obvious.
What else could be causing this error?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

This works without issue via Cloud Shell, which is what I need to replicate:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges" {
  name          = var.vpc_subnet_name
  ip_cidr_range = "10.51.0.0/20"
  region        = "europe-west2"
  network       = google_compute_network.custom-test.id
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "services"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.52.0.0/20"
  }
   secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "pods"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.53.0.0/20"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "custom-test" {
  name                    = "projectname-subnet-eu"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}
```

Comment: What is your VPC cidr?

Comment: @Marcin That'll be: 10.51.0.0/20

Comment: You cannot make up addresses that are not part of your VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Your subnets have wrong CIDRS. If you are not sure how they should be you can use [cidrsubnet](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrsubnet) function to give you correct CIDRs for your VPC. For example:

```
> cidrsubnet("10.51.0.0/20", 4, 0)
"10.51.0.0/24"
> cidrsubnet("10.51.0.0/20", 4, 1)
"10.51.1.0/24"
> cidrsubnet("10.51.0.0/20", 4, 2)
"10.51.2.0/24"
> cidrsubnet("10.51.0.0/20", 4, 3)
"10.51.3.0/24"
```

Comment: Thanks, although I need /20 addresses for the additional subnet ranges. Running the code manually via Cloud Shell works without issue when the ranges are explicitly stated without the Python script automatically updating the main.tf file.

Comment: @RobTheRobot16 Your subnets can't be the same as VPC. So you have to change VPC CIDR then.

Answer (score 1):

To find valid CIDR Address you can use,  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/networking-tools-python/tree/main/tools/cidr

Hopefully this should resolve your issue.